# How to authenticate in windows with custom credential provider?

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers

I've trying to make my custom credential provider with c++.I have read official documentation and checked existing samples. But, I misunderstand how to authenticate in windows, what function I should to use or where I should compare the entered password to login in system?

I have created a tile with one password field, but idk what I should do with entered data, how I should validate it and where I need to transfer it.

```
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSerialization(
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE* pcpgsr,
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs, 
    PWSTR* ppwzOptionalStatusText, 
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ppwzOptionalStatusText);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon);

    HRESULT hr;

    WCHAR wsz[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    DWORD cch = ARRAYSIZE(wsz);

    DWORD cb = 0;
    BYTE* rgb = NULL;

    if (GetComputerNameW(wsz, &cch))
    {
        PWSTR pwzProtectedPassword;

        hr = ProtectIfNecessaryAndCopyPassword(_rgFieldStrings[SFI_PASSWORD], _cpus, &pwzProtectedPassword);

        // Only CredUI scenarios should use CredPackAuthenticationBuffer.  Custom packing logic is necessary for
        // logon and unlock scenarios in order to specify the correct MessageType.
        if (CPUS_CREDUI == _cpus)
        {
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PWSTR pwzDomainUsername = NULL;
                hr = DomainUsernameStringAlloc(wsz, _rgFieldStrings[SFI_USERNAME], &pwzDomainUsername);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // We use KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON in both unlock and logon scenarios.  It contains a
                    // KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON to hold the creds plus a LUID that is filled in for us by Winlogon
                    // as necessary.
                    if (!CredPackAuthenticationBufferW((CREDUIWIN_PACK_32_WOW & _dwFlags) ? CRED_PACK_WOW_BUFFER : 0, pwzDomainUsername, pwzProtectedPassword, rgb, &cb))
                    {
                        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                        {
                            rgb = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cb);
                            if (rgb)
                            {
                                // If the CREDUIWIN_PACK_32_WOW flag is set we need to return 32 bit buffers to our caller we do this by 
                                // passing CRED_PACK_WOW_BUFFER to CredPacAuthenticationBufferW.
                                if (!CredPackAuthenticationBufferW((CREDUIWIN_PACK_32_WOW & _dwFlags) ? CRED_PACK_WOW_BUFFER : 0, pwzDomainUsername, pwzProtectedPassword, rgb, &cb))
                                {
                                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, rgb);
                                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    hr = S_OK;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = E_FAIL;
                        }
                        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pwzDomainUsername);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hr = E_FAIL;
                    }
                }
                CoTaskMemFree(pwzProtectedPassword);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON kiul;

            // Initialize kiul with weak references to our credential.
            hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit(wsz, _rgFieldStrings[SFI_USERNAME], pwzProtectedPassword, _cpus, &kiul);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // We use KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON in both unlock and logon scenarios.  It contains a
                // KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON to hold the creds plus a LUID that is filled in for us by Winlogon
                // as necessary.
                hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack(kiul, &pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &pcpcs->cbSerialization);
            }
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            ULONG ulAuthPackage;
            hr = RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(&ulAuthPackage);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage;
                pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_CSampleProvider;

                // In CredUI scenarios, we must pass back the buffer constructed with CredPackAuthenticationBuffer.
                if (CPUS_CREDUI == _cpus)
                {
                    pcpcs->rgbSerialization = rgb;
                    pcpcs->cbSerialization = cb;
                }

                // At this point the credential has created the serialized credential used for logon
                // By setting this to CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED we are letting logonUI know
                // that we have all the information we need and it should attempt to submit the 
                // serialized credential.
                *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
            }
            else 
            {
                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwErr);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: you transfer collected data to system in `GetSerialization` callback. credential provider must not authenticate user at all. however some time (usually in 2FA scenarios) credential provider, check by self credentials too - by `LsaLogonUser`. however final authentication is done inside lsass by authentication package

Comment: I got it, but when i try to login I always get Invalid user or password, I have created test user,  but it didn't help. May be I missed something...

Comment: You have to implement ICredentialProvider in a DLL. Now without code we can't help much...

Comment: Add GetSerialization code snippet

Comment: @AlexIvanov - this is not your code. *I always get Invalid user or password* - so exist some error(s) in your implementation.